# JDBCTemplate RowMapper para Nested POJOs

Tags: java, spring, query, jdbc

Vamos dizer que eu tenho os seguintes Pojos

```
public class Pedidos{
 private Strig codigo;
 private String nomePedido;
 private List<Dados> dadosPedido;
 //getters e setters}  
}
```

E

```
  public class Dados {
    private String nome;
    private int codigo;
 }
```

Eu sei que poderia usar um BeanPropertyRowMapper para popular uma lista de objetos de Pedidos, agora existe alguma forma de popular também o objeto Dados através da mesma query? Depois disso eu precisaria montar um XML onde cada Pedido teria a sua lista de Dados correspondente, eu achei uma pergunta similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718163/jdbctemplate-set-nested-pojo-with-beanpropertyrowmapper 
Porém no meu caso eu tenho também uma Lista de Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `RowMapper` não é uma boa solução para isso.

Eu estava aqui pensando em uma gambiarra para armazenar um mapa interno ou algo parecido, mas pesquisando por uma alternativa, encontrei esse código praticamente pronto usando o [`ResultSetExtractor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html):

```java
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM INVOICE inv JOIN INVOICE_LINE line " +
   + " on inv.id = line.invoice_id", new ResultSetExtractor<List<Invoice>>() {

    List<Invoice> extractData(ResultSet rs) {
        Map<Integer,Invoice> invoices = new HashMap<Integer,Invoice>();
        while(rs.hasNext()) {
            rs.next();
            Integer invoiceId = rs.getInd("inv.id");
            Invoice invoice = invoces.get(invoiceId);
            if (invoice == null) {
               invoice = invoiceRowMapper.mapRow(rs);
               invoices.put(invoiceId,invoice);
            }
            InvoiceItem item = invLineMapper.mapRow(rs);
            invoice.addItem(item);  
        }
        return invoices.values();
    }


});
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455220/spring-jdbc-rowmapper-usage-for-eager-fetches)

Com o `ResultSetExtractor` você faz a iteração manual sobre os resultados da query. Para cada registro:

1. Recupere o `id` do objeto da sua tabela principal (`Pedidos`)
2. Verifique se o `Pedido` já existe no mapa
   2.1 Se não existir, crie o produto e coloque no mapa
3. Recupere as informações da tabela `Dados`
4. Adicione os dados na lista do produto atual

O resultado final é um mapa de produtos, cada um com os respectivos dados preenchidos. Para retornar uma lista de produtos, use o método `keySet()` do mapa.